# Copy .txt file and capitalise first letter of each word and write to new file

Tags: python

I'm making a small script that opens the file_name and writes a copy of it to the destination .txt file but the first letter of each word is capitalised and all whitespace is just replaced by a singular space. I was trying to do this with the .capitalize method or the .capwords method.

```
def capitalise_words(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        capped = text_str.capwords()

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(capped)
```

I can't figure out how I can get this to work. Perhaps slicing to the first character of each word if I split them into a list and capitalizing it using .capitalize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need import the `string` module and then you can use `string.capwords()`:

```
import string

...

text_str = wordfile.read()
capped = string.capwords(text_str)
```

The reason for this is that `capwords()` is not a method of `str` object, it is a helper function in the `string` module.

So your original fixed:

```
import string


def capitalise_words(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        capped = string.capwords(text_str)

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(capped)
```

Edit:
If you don't want to import anything, you can simply use:

```
text_str = wordfile.read()
capped = ' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in text_str.split())
```

which is exactly what `string.capwords()` is actually doing under the hood.

Comment: Is there another way to do it without using capwords/importing string?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

**Ex:**

```
def capitalise_words(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        capped = text_str.title()

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(capped)
```

---

To replace all new-line chars use

```
capped = " ".join(word for word in text_str.splitlines()).title()
```

Comment: `str.title()` doesn't behave the same way as `string.capwords()`.

Comment: this also worked, but how do I go about replacing the whitespace (\n) with just a singular space?

Comment: @puppyonkik Replace newline character? if so use `capped = " ".join(word for word in text_str.splitlines()).title()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to replace all spaces with single space in a string and `.title()` to make first letter of every word as capital.

Try this,

```
import re

def capitalise_words(file_name, destination):
    with open(file_name) as wordfile:
        text_str = wordfile.read()
        capped = re.sub(' +', ' ', text_str).title()

    with open(destination, "w") as writefile:
        writefile.write(capped)
```

**Ex:**

```
>>> text_str = 'this   string    is created to      testing   '
>>> re.sub(' +', ' ', text_str).title()
'This String Is Created To Testing '
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
raw_text="""
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
"""
```

You can use `capitalize()' when iterate through a list of words.

```
txt_split = raw_text.split()

for i, word in enumerate(txt_split):
    txt_split[i] = word.capitalize()

txt_output = ' '.join(txt_split)

print(txt_output)
```

Output:

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit, Sed Do Eiusmod Tempor Incididunt Ut Labore Et Dolore Magna Aliqua. Ut Enim Ad Minim Veniam, Quis Nostrud Exercitation Ullamco Laboris Nisi Ut Aliquip Ex Ea Commodo Consequat. Duis Aute Irure Dolor In Reprehenderit In Voluptate Velit Esse Cillum Dolore Eu Fugiat Nulla Pariatur. Excepteur Sint Occaecat Cupidatat Non Proident, Sunt In Culpa Qui Officia Deserunt Mollit Anim Id Est Laborum.

`string.capwords()` is the same thing packed into a helper function for ease of use